# dpkg remove and don't work

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I tried to upgrade Ubuntu and some package broke, so I wrongly did this:

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/dpkg/*
```

and now I get this:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch but it is not installable
 wine1.4 : Depends: wine1.4-i386 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu5) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

and

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: error: unable to create new file '/var/lib/dpkg/info/format-new': No such file or directory
```

and

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch but it is not installable
 wine1.4 : Depends: wine1.4-i386 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu5) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```